# Creation of custom comparator for map in groovy

Tags: groovy

I have class in groovy

```
class WhsDBFile {
    String name
    String path
    String svnUrl
    String lastRevision
    String lastMessage
    String lastAuthor
}
```

and map object

```
def installFiles = [:]
```

that filled in loop by

```
WhsDBFile dbFile = new WhsDBFile()
installFiles[svnDiffStatus.getPath()] = dbFile
```

now i try to sort this with custom Comparator

```
        Comparator<WhsDBFile> whsDBFileComparator = new Comparator<WhsDBFile>() {
            @Override
            int compare(WhsDBFile o1, WhsDBFile o2) {
                if (FilenameUtils.getBaseName(o1.name) > FilenameUtils.getBaseName(o2.name)) {
                    return 1
                } else if (FilenameUtils.getBaseName(o1.name) > FilenameUtils.getBaseName(o2.name)) {
                    return -1
                }
                return 0
            }
        }
        installFiles.sort(whsDBFileComparator);
```

but get this error `java.lang.String cannot be cast to WhsDBFile`

Any idea how to fix this? I need to use custom comparator, cause it will be much more complex in the future.

p.s. full source of sample gradle task (description of WhsDBFile class is above):

```
    project.task('sample') << {
        def installFiles = [:]
        WhsDBFile dbFile = new WhsDBFile()
        installFiles['sample_path'] = dbFile
        Comparator<WhsDBFile> whsDBFileComparator = new Comparator<WhsDBFile>() {
            @Override
            int compare(WhsDBFile o1, WhsDBFile o2) {
                if (o1.name > o2.name) {
                    return 1
                } else if (o1.name > o2.name) {
                    return -1
                }
                return 0
            }
        }
        installFiles.sort(whsDBFileComparator);
    }
```

Comment: Any chance of a runnable example?

Comment: Added. It's part of my gradle script.

Comment: Why are you trying to preserve order with a map?

Comment: @christopher i will use map data type to find WhsDBFile object by filename.

Comment: Then you should make the key some value that you can use to lookup the `WhsDBFile` object. It shouldn't be used for searching. That defeats the point of a `Map`.

Comment: @christopher I use filename as key, and it's unique, Whats wrong with this key?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the key. It's the fact that you want to sort a map in general. It makes me worried that you're not using the correct data structure.

Comment: @christopher ok, what data type can you recommend to me, for this example?

Comment: Think you're sitting there map, when you only want to sort the list in one of the maps entries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to sort the entrySet() :

```
def sortedEntries = installFiles.entrySet().sort { entry1, entry2 -> 
  entry1.value <=> entry2.value 
}
```

you will have a collection of Map.Entry with this invocation. In order to have a map, you can then collectEntries() the result :

```
def sortedMap = installFiles.entrySet().sort { entry1, entry2 -> 
      ... 
}.collectEntries()
```

Answer (score 1):

`sort` can also take a closure as parameter which coerces to a `Comparator`'s `compare()` method as below. Usage of `toUpper()` method just mimics the implementation of `FilenameUtils.getBaseName()`.

```
installFiles.sort { a, b -> 
    toUpper(a.value.name) <=> toUpper(b.value.name)
}

// Replicating implementation of FilenameUtils.getBaseName()
// This can be customized according to requirement 
String toUpper(String a) {
    a.toUpperCase()
}
```